# Position grid at the center vertically?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

how do I position it at the center vertically?

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a">Block A</div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">Block B</div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">Block C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `vertical-align` property.

```
div[class|=ui-grid] { 
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px; }
div[class|=ui-block] { 
    background: blue;
    font: 10px Verdana;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
.ui-block-a { height: 100px; }
.ui-block-b { height: 50px; }
.ui-block-c { height: 200px; }
```

*`div[class|=ui-grid]` and `div[class|=ui-block]` are using the [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors).*

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/LzuYR/